# C# interface property min value

Tags: c#

Is there a way to set a min value for property in interface, so i don't have to set it in each class I am using that inteface?
For example I would like below code to set min value for altitude = 0.

```
{
    internal interface IAltitude
    {
        int altitude { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have tried something like this, but this is not working.

```
  internal interface IAltitude
    {
        int altitude { get{ return altitude; } set { if (altitude < 0)
                {
                    altitude = 0;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: separate out the validation - then the validation can be used in each class - plentty of os libs out there

Comment: An interface has no business-logic like argument-checks. The business-logic is implemented in **classes**.

Comment: Why not use `uint`?

Comment: It won't be possible directly the way you want, but if you can provide your holistic requirement, i might be possible to restrict values from design perspective. e.g. have some limitation set in implementer at factory itself or instead of using Setter in property. make it read only and have Setter method instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to implement code in interfaces, you would have to write an abstract base class.

Since C# 8 it is possible to provide default implementations in interfaces, however it is not possible to declare a field. [Default interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods.).

It might be an option to use an `uint` for the altitude, then no negative values would be possible. But if you need any kind of range check it is better to use some kind of ValidationAttribute, e.g. a [RangeValidation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute?view=net-6.0)